# Categorical variable in mixed effects?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, experiment-design, ordinal-data

I have a study like this: We recruits 20 teacher to participate in the research study. We use a step-wedge design where 10 of them are randomly assigned to a group that will receive an app and 10 teachers  are randomly assigned to a group that will receive the app after the study is complete . The study lasts 8 months. The app will be used to reduce documentation burden of teachers.

I have 3 variables :
1- Percentage of using the app over traditional way of checking documents (%) Captured monthly for each teacher

2- The total time each teacher spent on document weather traditional or on the app (Time in hour) Captured monthly for each teacher

3- In the past month, I felt burned out from my work , Response options are: Never, Some of the time, Most of the time and All of the time . Captured monthly for each teacher

So we have 8 rounds of data. To answer teacher documentation burden, I have used mixed effects model where the dependent variable is the total time each teacher spent on documents.
However, I am not sure how to examine teacher burnout?

Please help me how can I handle this categorical (ordinal variable )in mixed effects model and also if I need to use ANOVA repeated measure?

Comment: "*I have used mixed effects model where the dependent variable is the total time each teacher spent on documents.*" Could you write out the model in your question?